# Is there a term for when fiction refers to fiction

Tags: terminology

In the movie *E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial*, two characters are talking and one refers to something from Star Trek.

Here is the lines from that dialogue ([source IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083866/quotes/?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu)),

> Elliott: He's a man from outer space and we're taking him to his spaceship.
>   Greg: Well, can't he just beam up?
>  Elliott: This is *reality*,
>   Greg.

So a fictional movie is referring to another fictional story.  Is there a term for this?

Comment: Would you accept TVTropes as a canonical source for literary terms? They have an article about this: [This Is Reality](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThisIsReality).

Comment: @Philipp I would accept ideas from TVTropes, I'm not looking for definitive definition, just terms and ideas that explore this concept.  The link brings up another thought about the quote from the movie.  I find it one thing for an character in fiction to say, this is reality.  I find it another for a fictional character to say this fictional world is reality, but that other fictional world is not.

Comment: ["Do not use this tag to ask about terminology of specific topics that are not related to the craft of writing. In these cases you might want to check out EnglishLanguage&Usage.StackExchange and their single-word-requests tag."](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) The requested term is tangentially related to writing at best and only in so much as it is a concept that appears in written media, not that it is part of the writing process. You're more likely to get a broader range of answers on EL&U than here as that site is more geared toward this type of request.

Comment: I initially misunderstood your question.  But now that I understand it, I think it should be migrated to EL&U.

Comment: EL&U is not crazy about questions about jargon used primarily within a particular field, those should be asked in the more specific SE site. So if this is about how writers refer to this practice when discussing the craft amongst themselves, it belongs here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do terminology requests here. If EL&U won't take this either perhaps try Movie&TV though I don't know if you will have any luck. Regardless of other sites policies though, it is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm confused, there is a terminology tag, so what do you mean 'we don't do terminology requests here'? Also, is flashback part of the craft of writing? If it is, then why is allusion not part of the craft of writing. If flashback is not part of the craft, then what is it?

Comment: It's referring to a real television show (about a fictional situation). This is no different from referring to literature like *Treasure Island,*  or *The Iliad,* or some story your mom told you.

Comment: @Bob516 I guess I'm the only genre geek on the board. The term is *meta.* Answer added below.

Answer (score 18):

*Allusion*, may be the term you are looking for.

> Allusion is a brief and indirect reference to a person, place, thing
>   or idea of historical, cultural, literary or political significance.
>   It does not describe in detail the person or thing to which it refers.
>   It is just a passing comment and the writer expects the reader to
>   possess enough knowledge to spot the allusion and grasp its importance
>   in a text. https://literarydevices.net/allusion/

While it does include things other than fiction for possible references, it's still fairly specific.  The example you provided falls well within this definition. Perhaps "literary allusion" would be more fitting.

Comment: I'm not sure about this in relation to the example provided. While they don't explicitly say *Star Trek*, the two are so closely linked that it feels more like directly referencing than alluding to it.

Comment: I feel the "Beam Me Up" = Trek, despite never being said directly in it.  That's what this is an allusion, and not a direct reference.    It *alludes* to a frequently shown element in the show, and how it doesn't apply here (but it solved an issue of Drama for the show -- allowing "interplanetary" things to enter and exit the ship as quickly and easily as they can enter an office in a terrestrial show.  )

Comment: I agree that this is allusion rather than a direct reference, but that doesn't seem to be what the question is asking.  What this answers is the question "What do you call it when someone refers to something indirectly, without actually saying its name?" But the question is "What do you call it when a fictional character says something like 'This isn't fiction but reality' and essentially lies to the reader?"  Because obviously, ET is fiction, not reality. Reinforced [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45918/is-there-a-term-for-when-fiction-refers-to-fiction#comment76858_45918).

Answer (score 10):

I think Allusion is the best term for this scenario, but there can be other world-breaking type of scenarios.  I *adore* **[MetaFiction](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MetafictionDemandedThisIndex)**, so the link to [Intertextuality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertextuality) is a good starting place, and if you have time, yes, TV Tropes can show you a zillion parallels.

Some more things to explore:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-reference
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostasis_(literature) (this was averted -- the characters in *E.T.* still believe they are "real" -- but if not, could they cross fictional paths and use a transporter?
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_literature

Comment: This. Like the Necronomicon clearly shows.

Answer (score 0):

There is the general term **self-reflexive**, referring to when something refers to itself. (Now, if I can find a reference...)  Ah, here we go -- [Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-reflexive):

> marked by or making reference to its own artificiality or contrivance.
>   *self-reflexive fiction*

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the term you are looking for yet, it is ["meta."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meta) This term derives from "metafiction."

From MW.com

> 1 informal : showing or suggesting an explicit awareness of itself or oneself as a member of its category : cleverly self-referential

> 2 informal : concerning or providing information about members of its own category

Your example fits more into definition 2, while other meta examples are more self-aware and even "break the fourth wall" to comment on themselves.

Examples of the use of "meta":

[Why Rick and Morty gets so meta](https://www.reddit.com/r/rickandmorty/comments/gx0zi3/why_rick_and_morty_get_so_meta/)

[‘Scream’ Turns 20: 10 Reasons It’s Still a Meta-Horror Masterpiece](https://www.thewrap.com/sceam-20-anniversary-10-reasons-why-scream-is-a-meta-horror-masterpiece/)

[Rick and Morty's Latest Meta Episode 'Bashes' Its Own Narrative](https://www.cbr.com/rick-morty-latest-episode-bash-own-narrative/)

[What’s The Meta? How The Cabin in the Woods Subverted Horror](https://medium.com/@jamesandrews10/whats-the-meta-how-the-cabin-in-the-woods-subverted-horror-67978839584b)

[8 Unapologetically Meta SF/F Novels](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/8-unapologetically-meta-sff-novels/)